# How true is the Soviet killing quota under Stalin?

Tags: soviet-union, communism, stalin

In [The Soviet Story](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTJQXKUR6mM) from 1:37:54 to 1:38:54, killing quotas of Soviet citizens are talked about. I could not find any concrete reason, evidence, or documentation suggesting that such "killing quotas " existed inflicted by the Soviet government on its own people and find it to make very little sense.

Can someone verify the claims made in this video and back them up with some evidence as they seem exaggerated to me off the bat.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: Does [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Soviet_Story#Criticism) help? e.g. "I had only been an expert there and I can only answer for what I am saying there myself. I had told to Šnore that some of his narratives are obvious forgeries he was tricked by. For example, Beria—Müller agreement on killing Jews together""

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: Is this perhaps ore suited to [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 5):

This quota ("лимиты") was introduced in the infamous [NKVD Order No. 00447](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NKVD_Order_No._00447) of July 30, 1937 (yes, as Mark says, Wikipedia does help, you just have to know where to look; Russian Wikipedia mirror is much more detailed than the English link I gave). If and when I have more time, I will add more on this. The only surprising thing about these quotas is that they surprise anybody: After all, USSR was a country of planned economy.

Comment: A planned economy where they kill their own citizens?

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz: Sure. And slave labor in GULAG is a big part of the planned economy, which means that smart GULAG officials even start to protect (up to a point) their prisoners so they can fulfill their 5 year plans! Zavenyagin was one of those.

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz that order is a result of a very complex situation. It must be viewed in a context. Those was not just dumb repressions for the fun of it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what situation you talk about?

Comment: @Zmur: Nobody says it was done for fun, the Party line was that all the killings were done in order to "protect the Socialist Motherland from the class enemies." In order to explain the sudden increase of the number of class enemies Stalin came up with the theory of the "increased class straggle during construction and development of socialism." If one wants to understand what was really going on, the book by Robert Conquest "[The Great Terror](https://www.amazon.com/Great-Terror-Reassessment-Robert-Conquest/dp/0195317009)" is still one of the best.

Comment: @MoisheKohan that has nothing to do with the political slogans. The rural area was a mess back then. There were numerous cases of deliberate sabotage on all levels. NKVD itself was extremely corrupt organization. That is why Ezhov himself was shot. His interrogation protocols are available now BTW.
This whole mess is impossible to describe in a comment. The great purge was a radical measure causes of which root from the civil war times.

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz try google translating this page: http://wiki.istmat.info/%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%84:%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8
that should give a brief insight. But there is much much more to the problem.